# Why does powershell script had different access right when called from task scheduler than when run directly?

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to automate regular backups from server A to server B. For this, I created powershell scripts. Desired behaviour is : Sort through files in A:\files, get the most recently modified and copy it to B:\backup, then clean-up B:\backup to keep only X most recent copies of file. I would also like to keep multiple backups sorted like this: daily, weekly, monthly, yearly, in B:\backup\daily, B:\backup\weekly, etc... For this, I made a parameter switch (-mode D/W/M/Y) on the main script that then calls the others as appropriate.

It works perfectly if I do right click/run in powershell. If I try to run them through task scheduler, I get a file access error to server B. Files are always run form server A (Windows Server 2012). I always use the full path for server B (not the drive letter).

Backup script (bu_template.ps1) with access fault is:

```
#-----------------------SET SOURCE AND DESTINATION FOLDERS HERE-------------------------------------------

param([string]$src,
[string]$dest,
[int]$nb=10)

#do not modify below this line
#-------------------------------- DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE ------------------------------------------------
function create-item ($path){
    try{
        $testpath=Test-Path -Path $path
        If ($testpath){
            "destination "+$path+" exists"
        }
        Else{
            If($path.split("\")[-1] -like "*.*"){
                New-Item -Path $path -ItemType File
            }
            Else{
                New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
    "access error : "+$PSItem | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    }
}

try {
    $logFile="back-up_log.txt"
    .\log_init.ps1 $logFile "New back-up job"
}
catch{
    "log init error : "+$PSItem | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
}

try {
    create-item -path $dest | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    Get-ChildItem -Path $src -File | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First $nb | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
}
catch[System.IO.IOException]{
    "access error : "+$PSItem | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
}
catch{
    "back-up error : "+$PSItem | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
}
```

I seem to get an access error at Test-Path.

This script is called from my main script (bu_task.ps1):

```
#-----------------------SET SOURCE AND DESTINATION FOLDERS HERE-------------------------------------------
param(
[string]$mode=" ",
[string]$src="A:\files",
[string]$dest="B:\backup",
[int]$nb=12
)
#-------------------------------- DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE ------------------------------------------------
#log init
$logFile="regular_bu_log.txt"
.\log_init.ps1 $logFile "Full backup job"

#mode selection
switch ($mode){
    D {$dest=$dest+"\daily"
        #clean src folder
        .\clean-up.ps1 -src $src -nb $nb
        }
    W {$dest=$dest+"\weekly"}
    M {$dest=$dest+"\monthly"}
    Y {$dest=$dest+"\yearly"}
    default{ 
        $dest=$dest+"\default"
        $mode+" - no mode selected" | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
        }
}

#back-up job
.\bu_template.ps1 -src $src -dest $dest -nb 1


#clean bu folder
.\clean-up.ps1 -src $dest -nb $nb
```

Up to now, I tried running a powershell directly from task scheduler, then running a bat that calls the powershell script. I double checked that the task is setup as "running with highest priviledge" and that it is running from the same account that I use for right click/run in powershell and that this account has access.

I also tried to add a cd A:\scripts to make sure I execute form the same location.

I made sure that the script is still running with admin privileges form the task scheduler (and it is) with this:

```
$id = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

$p = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($id)

if ($p.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
    log "I am an admin"
```

I am confused as to what changes in the permissions when the script is ran through the task scheduler vs directly with the same account. I tried calling it multiple way, my logs prove that the script starts with admin rights.

Comment: log "I am an admin" should have {} around it otherwise it will always write to the log.
If (condition) {code block}

Comment: If you run the whoami command, is the output the same for both?

Comment: Apologies, I has to step back from this one for a while. I am admin has the {}, that was me retyping this part from memory at the end of the day...
Regardless, I tried using whoami cmdlet as it is much simpler and the output is the same (serverName\username). Considering that the task is ran with higher privileges, sounds like the issue is not with the user...